# Ajax Setting Session ID Failing Coordination with PHP query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, session

So I am trying to make a discussion board and I have a table of posts being queried in one column of a table on the discussion board page. I then have the buttons of those post set up to a function onclick (where I am passing the post ID and then posting it to set_id.php to set as $_SESSION['name'] = $_REQUEST['name']):

scripts.js:

```
function getcomments(id){
    $("#success_child").empty();
    $.post("discussion_topics/set_id.php", { 
    "name": id}).done($("#success_child").load("discussion_topics/comments.php",      
    function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){

        if(statusTxt == "error")
            alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
    }));
```

}

The problem is, although the Post ID is being set correctly, the php file being loaded will load the previously set SESSION variable that is the post ID. I have absolutely no idea why.

Basically, the SEssion variable is being set properly, however, when a new post is clicked, it will query in the comments.php the old session ID, then when you click again it will query that last one that didn't show. Basically a delay somehow. But it is not a time delay because I have tried that.

HELP!

comment.php:

```
<?php

session_start();
echo $_SESSION['name'];

function draw_table(){

    /* draw table */
    $table = '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="discuss_table">';



        //Connect To Database

        $hostname="localHost";
        $username="removed";
        $password="removed";
        $dbname="removed";
        $usertable="replys";

        mysql_connect($hostname,$username, $password) or die ("<html>    <script>alert('Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.'),history.go(-1)</script>");
        mysql_select_db($dbname);

        # Check If Record Exists
        $id = $_SESSION['name'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM $usertable WHERE post_id = $id";

        $result = mysql_query($query);

        if($result)
        {

              while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
              {

                //build table for post                                            
                $date = date("M d Y h:ia e", strtotime($row["date"]));
                $table.="<tr>";
                    $table.= "<p class=\"discussion_title\">";
                $table.= "<b>".$row["title"]."</b>"."<br>";
                $table.=$row["name"].", ".$date." for topic ".$row["topic"]."<br>";
                $table.=$row["content"]."<br>";
                $table.="<button  class=\"makecomment_buttons\">Reply</button>";    

                $table.="</p></tr>";

              }

        }





//end the table
$table.= '</table>';

//all done, return result
return $table;
}

echo draw_table();
echo "<br>";


?>
```

set_id.php

```
<?php

session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = $_REQUEST['name'];

?>
```

Comment: Also, any changes I make to the original file won't display. Is this maybe an error on the hosting side not the code?

Comment: Share php and html code

Comment: Alright I added the important files   @Rishi